# PHP min not working correctly

Tags: php

I have an array with 3 values(56.767, 360.997, 579.728). These are in an array($distance).

Well, when I run the min($distance) I get '360.997'. What gives?

```
<?php

include('mysql_connect.php');

$MasterState = 'CA';

$query = 'select * from estes_term where Dest_State = "'.$MasterState.'"';
$result = mysql_query($query); 

if($result) {
    $row = @mysqli_fetch_row($result);
}

$Term_Zip = array();
$Distance = array();
$i = '0';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $Term_Zip[] = $row['Term_Zip'];
    $Distance_xml = file_get_contents('http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/ua6z0ep0djB3zHGz5Z40hONMVc8yuXgY8nx8BX8OhKSRrzqxzvyRjmDeyMM3J32S/distance.xml/90077/'.$Term_Zip[$i].'/mile');
    $Distance[] = $Distance_xml;
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($Term_Zip);
var_dump($Distance).'<br />';
$test1 = min($Distance);
$test = (array_keys($Distance, min($Distance)));

echo '<br />';
echo 'Min'.min($Distance);

?>
```

Comment: Your values are probably stored as strings, not numbers.

Comment: You've got a var_dump in there, what is its output?  My suspicion is you're storing strings which will get sorted by alphanumerical value rather than numerical value.

Comment: Are they stored as numbers or as string? Find out with var_dump, I'm guessing string, in which case the result is correct.

Comment: make sure they are integers/floats and nit strings

Comment: Try floatval()'ing each distance before using min()

Comment: It is strings. How do I make them something else that will work?

Comment: Also do `var_dump ($distance); echo '<br>';` instead, as what you've got may result in an unintended cast to string

Comment: Josh, do you mean like this '$Distance[] = floatval($Distance_xml);'? If so that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As @Rocket pointed out, your variables are stored as strings, not floats. This, the character "3" is smaller than "5", so it's the first one. To avoid this use [Type Juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) or `floatval()` in your code to assure your vars are float as:

```
$Distance[] = floatval(trim($Distance_xml));
```

Comment: When I do this I get '0' for all values.

Comment: Note that `_xml` is surely a really bad variable name for a "float" data type (while it *might* be correct, writing that line made me cringe).

Comment: Still zeros. I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: uhm... I don't know what to say then. You should probably start to test your code more extensively, part by part, to see where it's actually failing. what does `var_dump($distance);` return?

Comment: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(70) "
56.767"
  [1]=>
  string(71) "
360.997"
  [2]=>
  string(71) "
579.728"
}

Comment: Updated with `trim()`

Comment: Still getting zeros. This sucks. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this... We are converting all the array elements to `float` using `array_map` and then finding the `min` value from it.

```
<?php
$arr= array(56.767, 360.997, 579.728);
echo min(array_map('floatval',$arr));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
56.767
```

**EDIT :**

To get the key , you can make use of **`array_search()`**

```
$key = array_search(min(array_map('floatval',$arr)), $arr);
```

Comment: I really need the key of the lowest number so I can refer to it again to get the zip code.